# Как отключить сортировку строк в json объекте QJsonObject?

Tags: json, qt, qt5

В методе `loadJsonData` заполняю данными `QJsonObject`. Из этого объекта создаю `QJsonDocument`. Ковертирую в `QString` и сохраняю в файле. 
Хочу чтобы последовательность в которой я заполнял `QJsonObject` осталась и в файле. Подскажите как это сделать.

```
QJsonDocument doc(loadJsonData(Element));
saveFile(doc.toJson(QJsonDocument::Indented));

QJsonObject *TreeModel::loadJsonData(SCommonElement *curElement)
{
 QJsonObject *joElement = new QJsonObject;

 joElement->insert(JS_ABSOLUTEID,       QJsonValue::fromVariant(curElement->elementConf.absoluteId));
 joElement->insert(JS_PRIVATEID,        QJsonValue::fromVariant(curElement->elementConf.privateId)); 
 joElement->insert(JS_COMPOSITENAME,    QJsonValue::fromVariant(curElement->elementConf.compositeName));
 joElement->insert(JS_PRIVATENAME,      QJsonValue::fromVariant(curElement->elementConf.privateName));
 joElement->insert(JS_DTCREATE,         QJsonValue::fromVariant(curElement->elementConf.dtCreate));
 joElement->insert(JS_DTMODIFY,         QJsonValue::fromVariant(curElement->elementConf.dtModify));
 joElement->insert(JS_COMMENTS,         QJsonValue::fromVariant(curElement->elementConf.comments));
 joElement->insert(JS_CHILDNEXTID,      QJsonValue::fromVariant(curElement->elementConf.childNextId));

 return joElement;
} 

void TreeModel::saveFile(QString Source)
{
 QString FilePath="d:/Data.json";
 QFile file(FilePath);

 if(!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
 {
    QMessageBox::critical(NULL, QObject::tr("Saving file"), QString("Error saving file [%1]. Check existing configuration file!\nSystem error - %2").arg(FilePath).arg(file.errorString()));
    return;
 }
 QTextStream stream(&file);
 stream << Source << endl;
}
```

Результат:

```
{
 "absoluteId": 1000001,
 "childNextId": 4,
 "comments": "This is fork 1",
 "compositeName":   "module100_path1_path2_class1_fork1",
 "dtCreate": "2017-08-31 10:44:42",
 "dtModify": "2017-08-31 10:44:42",
 "privateId": 0,
 "privateName": "fork1"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сортировка в JSON не настраивается. Стандартом предусмотрено вывод строк в JSON-объекте в алфавитном порядке.